# Simple JavaScript, cant get my head around it

Tags: javascript

```
x = 1;

var add = function (x) {
  x++;
  return x;
};

setTimeout(add, 1000);

console.log(x);
```

Why is this not working properly? Console only says 1 and stops, but I want it the addition of x every time the add handler is called with the timeout property (1 2 3 4 and soforth). I know I can just use a for loop for this. But I'd like to know if it could be done this way also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous. You tell it to execute `add` 1 second (1000 milliseconds) later, and it does. In the meantime, `console.log(x)` is executed, and logs the current value of `x`, 1.

In the question you say you want to see the value constantly incrementing. For that, you need to use code more like this:

```
var x = 1;

function add() {
  x++;
  console.log(x);
};

setInterval(add, 1000);
```

EDIT: Also, look at Quentin's bullet point 2 about masking the global variable.

Comment: It didnt work with setTimeout, but when I used setInterval instead, it worked perfectly, thanks. I will research the exact differences of the two on the internet.

Comment: @sheez: `setTimeout` executes it once, `setInterval` executes it every *n* milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

1. You only call `console.log` at the start. Move it inside the function so it runs every time the function does.
2. You have a (never populated) argument to the function called `x`, this masks the global one. Remove it.

Such:

```
var x = 1;

function add() {
  x++;
  console.log(x);
};

setTimeout(add, 1000);
```